# Deploy button to manually redeploy in Netbeans while working with deployOnSave disabled mode

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, netbeans-plugins

Is there any way to manually redeploy project after making certain changes to source ?

I disabled `deployOnSave` option in Netbeans to prevent unnecessary redeploys while I make trivial changes in code. Perhaps a redeploy button in toolbar or anything like that would be helpful.

---

Using Netbeans 7.2

Answer (score 4):

1. Right Click on Project
2. Properties
3. Run Sub Menu
4. Deploy On Save Check-box (uncheck this One)

Put a shortcut key for deploy

1. Tools Menu
2. Options
3. Key Map Sub Menu
4. Search Deploy And Set Your Key Combination

Comment: How would you do this in Netbeans 8.2 ? The "Deploy" function is not in the Key Map menu :/ nor can I find the "Deploy on Save" checkbox in project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add the server to your managed servers on Netbeans, got to `Windows -> Services`. When you've added your server edit the properties of your project and set the just added server as the default server for the project. Now you can just do a `clean` from the toolbar button and then a `run` when you want to deploy your project.

Comment: that's not like the normal redeploy like when deployOnSave is enabled & takes much longer time. That's not an optimal way to redeploy!

Comment: I don't see the differences between a `run` button on the toolbar and a `redeploy` button

Answer (score 0):

When you disable **deployOnSave** then when you want to **re-deploy** just enable **deployOnSave** in project properties.
Server will re-deploy and you can disable **deployOnSave** again.

You can add shortcut for accessing project settings.

Clicking **Debug** or **Run** button will start full deploy, eg. for maven project it will starts with tests, etc..., un-deploy, deploy.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this way:

1. Right click on project > Properties > Build > Compile > Compile on Save is checked.
2. Attach Debugger (google for it)
3. Debug > Apply Code Changes